# Read encoded frames from webcam with python opencv

Tags: opencv, gstreamer, video-capture, python-gstreamer

At this moment I have the `VideoImageTrack` class I show bellow (adapted from [here](https://github.com/aiortc/aiortc/blob/master/examples/apprtc/apprtc.py)) that returns an `av`  `VideoFrame`. The script I show works fine. My problem is that the frame encoding step:

```
VideoFrame.from_ndarray(image, format="bgr24")
```

is quite slow.

Is there a `gstreamer` pipeline that outputs the already encoded frame and iterable with `python-opencv` `read()`?

```
class VideoImageTrack(VideoStreamTrack):
    """
    A video stream track that returns a rotating image.
    """

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()  # don't forget this!

        self.video = cv2.VideoCapture("v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw,width=640,height=480,framerate=15/1,bitrate=250000  ! appsink")


    async def recv(self):
        pts, time_base = await self.next_timestamp()

        retval, image = self.video.read()
        frame = VideoFrame.from_ndarray(image, format="bgr24")
        frame.pts = pts
        frame.time_base = time_base

        return frame
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't know if processing will be faster but you can try to use GStreamer's [videoconvert](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/videoconvert/index.html?gi-language=python) that [transcodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcoding) video frames between many formats.

Example pipeline:

```
v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=BGR,width=640,height=480,framerate=15/1 ! appsink
```